# How to show $a_n = (1 + \frac{2}{n} )^n$ is bounded above?

Tags: analysis

Can someone help me about this question?
I have proved $a_n = (1 + \frac{2}{n})^n$ is increasing, but I have been confused by how to show it is bounded above.

I have show that for $1 \leq k \leq n$

${n \choose k} \frac{2^k}{n^k} = \frac{2^k}{k!} \frac{n(n-1)···(n-k)}{n^k}  \leq \frac{2^k}{k!}$

Then, I was confusing on how can I show $a_n$ is bounded above a number.

Need someone's help, thanks.

Comment: The inequality you are wanting to show follows from the fact that $n(n-1)\cdots (n-k)\leq n^k$ as $n\geq n-1\geq n-2 \geq \cdots \geq n-k$. Thus $n(n-1)\cdots (n-k)/n^k\leq 1$.

Comment: Looks like you could use the binomial theorem to show that $a_n$ is bounded based on the inequality you have already proven.

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185660/prove-1-frac1nn-is-bounded-above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof, without logs/exp that (1+x/n)^n converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190216/proof-without-logs-exp-that-1x-nn-converges)

Comment: It is equivalent to prove that $\log(a_n)$ is bounded from above.

Comment: Wouldn’t be simpler to start with $\sqrt{a_n}=\left(1+\frac 1{\frac 2n}\right)^\frac n2\to e$?

Comment: @WindSoul Sir, so my goal is to show if $\sqrt(a_n)$ is bounded above, then $a_n$ is also bounded above right?

Comment: @JeanMarie alright Sir, I will check it, thanks sir.